# CURL -F request with Retrofit2

Tags: android, curl, retrofit, retrofit2

I am trying to upload a file to the Upload care.

request:

```
curl -F "UPLOADCARE_PUB_KEY=demopublickey"  -F "file=@1467868509.png" "https://upload.uploadcare.com/base/"
```

response:

```
{"file":"4231e3a9-4480-4614-800b-68173595742d"}
```

Here is some documentation: https://uploadcare.com/documentation/upload/#upload-body

I want to use the Retrofit2 instead of the library of the UploadCare.

How I can convert the CURL request to Retrofit2 call?

UPD:
here is my test code:

```
public static
void uploadFile(File file, Context context) {
    FileUploadService service = ServiceGenerator.createService(FileUploadService.class);

    RequestBody requestFile =
            RequestBody.create(

                    MediaType.parse(context.getContentResolver().getType(Uri.fromFile(file))),
                    file
            );

    MultipartBody.Part content = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.getName(), requestFile);

    RequestBody publicKey = RequestBody.create(okhttp3.MultipartBody.FORM, UPLOADCARE_PUB_KEY);

    Call<ResponseBody> call = service.upload(publicKey, content);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>()
    {
        @Override
        public
        void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call,
                        Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            Log.e("#### Upload", "success");
        }

        @Override
        public
        void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("#### Upload error:", t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}

public interface FileUploadService {
    @Multipart
    @POST("base")
    Call<ResponseBody> upload(
            @Part("UPLOADCARE_PUB_KEY") RequestBody description,
            @Part MultipartBody.Part file
    );
}

public static
class ServiceGenerator {

    private static final String BASE_URL = "https://upload.uploadcare.com";

    private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
            new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

    private static Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

    private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient =
            new OkHttpClient.Builder();

    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }
}
```

Response from server:

```
Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=405, message=Method Not Allowed, url=https://upload.uploadcare.com/base/}
```

UPD2: It is my old function, it works:

```
@NonNull
public static
String uploadFileOld(@NonNull final File param) {
          String errorMessage = "";
    String response = "";

    try {

        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(param.getAbsolutePath());
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);

        ContentBody contentFile = new ByteArrayBody(bos.toByteArray(), param.getName());
        ContentBody contentKey = new StringBody(UPLOADCARE_PUB_KEY);

        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        reqEntity.addPart("file", contentFile);
        reqEntity.addPart("UPLOADCARE_PUB_KEY", contentKey);

        response = multipost(UPLOADCARE_URL, reqEntity);
        if (response != null) {
            return response;
        }
        errorMessage = "Upload failed";
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        errorMessage = "Upload exception: " + ex.getMessage();
    }

    errorMessage = errorMessage.replace("\"", "'");
    response = "{\"error\": \"" + errorMessage + "\"}";
    return response;
}

private 
String multipost(String urlString, MultipartEntity reqEntity) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        conn.addRequestProperty("Content-length", reqEntity.getContentLength() + "");
        conn.addRequestProperty(reqEntity.getContentType().getName(), reqEntity.getContentType().getValue());

        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        reqEntity.writeTo(os);
        os.close();

        conn.connect();

        if (conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            return readStream(conn.getInputStream());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: till now have you developed any retrofit call ? How much have you tried ?

Comment: https://medium.com/@adinugroho/upload-image-from-android-app-using-retrofit-2-ae6f922b184c#.874wq48m5

Comment: https://androidmads.blogspot.com/2016/06/upload-file-to-server-using-retrofit-in.html

Comment: It does not work - I receive the "Method Not Allowed" message in onResponse(call, response)